# Turn a string into list elements

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string array returned from a database that needs parsing:

x = "[SD, 1G, 2G, 3G+]"

If they were integers I could do:

json.loads(x) and return a list of elements, however due to them being characters I can't.

Is there an easy implementation for this?

desired output: ['SD', '1G', '2G', '3G+'] (type: list)

Comment: Have you tried using the `strip` and `split` string methods?

Comment: Why do you have such non-standard lists in your database in the first place…?

Comment: Because I'm using MySQL, which isn't designed to handle arrays. Bespoke design solution...

Comment: And that data couldn't be stored in some standard format in MySQL, like JSON?

Comment: I'm using an older version of MariaDB that doesn't support JSON.

Comment: That just means you can't query based on the contents of the JSON string. You can still store JSON as regular string and parse it in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) assuming that you are sure there will never be any surrounding whitespace:

```
>>> x = "[SD, 1G, 2G, 3G+]"
>>> xs = x[1:-1].split(", ")
>>> xs
['SD', '1G', '2G', '3G+']
```

If there is a possibility for that you could call [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.strip) on `x` beforehand:

```
>>> x = " [SD, 1G, 2G, 3G+]   "
>>> xs = x.strip()[1:-1].split(", ")
>>> xs
['SD', '1G', '2G', '3G+']
```

Comment: Ah yes. forgot I could use split... And could even map each element to remove whitespace if any... i.e. map(lambda i: i.strip(), xs)

Comment: You could use a list comprehension in that case: `[v.strip() for v in x.strip()[1:-1].split(", ")]`

Comment: @arsenal88 don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

What about just use `yaml`:

*(You need `pip install pyyaml`)*

```
>>> import yaml
>>> s = "[SD, 1G, 2G, 3G+]"
>>> yaml.safe_load(s)
['SD', '1G', '2G', '3G+']
```